# setting session expire with php config?

Tags: php, session

**UPDATED**

So I am running into another problem that I think is pretty much the same thing.  I am using silex and I want the session to be stored for 5 days.  I give the have the following values:

```
session.cookie_lifetime: 432000
session.gc_maxlifetime: 432000
session.gc_probability: 100
session.gc_divisor: 100
```

So from my understanding since probability and divisor are the same number, gc should happen every page load and the session file (using php native file handler for sessions) should be kept around for 432000 (60 * 60 * 24 * 5) seconds without any activity on them.  This issue is even with these value, my session seems to expire between 1-2 hours of no activity.

I even tried seeting the gc_maxlifetime to 5 and that seemed to work fine so it makes me think something else is being triggered before gc_maxlifetime is.

Are there any other values I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The server decides when to clear up stale sessions.

This happens at certain times, depending on a random number and the chance you gave it (in php.ini).

Look for session.gc_divisor.

So in your situation, your cookie with the PHPSESSID is still there, and your browser sends it as it should to the server, but the server cannot find a corresponding session.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change a couple more variables in your php.ini
.check this [link](http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/manually-set-php-session-timeout-php-session/)